# Scrolling UICollectionView to specific point upon letting go of scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

When the user lets go of scrolling in a UICollectionView, I want it to scroll to a relevant point. In this example, I'll use `CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100)`.

I've previously tried doing this:

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    self.collectionView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100), animated: true)
}
```

But that gives an animation that starts with a CurveEaseIn. If the user were to let go as they were dragging, this would give an odd appearance as the dragging suddenly halts as they lift their finger, then starts moving again.

So I tried doing this with my own animation instead:

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(
    0.3,
    delay: 0,
    options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut,
    animations: {
        () -> Void in
        self.collectionView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100), animated: false)
    }, completion: nil)
```

The animation take place just like I'd want, but the cells which would be off screen at the end of the animation disappear immediately. The same thing happens if I replace `setContentOffset()` with `contentOffset =`.

So then somebody suggest that instead, I use the `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:` method. So I did:

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
    targetContentOffset.memory = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100)
}
```

What happens now is the animation occurs with the given velocity, so if the user lifts their finger, then it slowly makes its way to the desired location, with 0 velocity.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Question is: How do I make it animate to a specific point, like it does in my 2nd code sample, but without collection view cells disappearing.